# Base 64 encoded image not displaying properly in browser?

Tags: html

I have a png image in the form of a base64 encoded string that is not displaying properly in html. Here is my code:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

If you try this in your browser it is not showing the whole image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not adding the entire image, the Base64 string is just a partial image ?

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle with this code.

Comment: The encoded string is most likely corrupted. Where did you get it/how did you create it?

Comment: The source is either corrupted or it might be truncated.

Comment: The encoded string is generated from a wacom STU-300 signature tablet. Its a png of a signature

Comment: It is clear that the device is giving an corrupted base64 data. Please verify if the device is working correctly. Also you can always copy the base64 data into your browser URL to verify if the data is correct. Without the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged as PHP we'll review some tools we can use to diagnose the issue:

- [base64_decode()](http://php.net/base64_decode) will get the original binary data back
- [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) can save the decoded data into a file
- [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) can be used to read the metadata regarding picture dimensions

If we use that to compose a little helper program we find out that:

- Expected picture size is `width="300" height="150"`
- Actual picture looks like this in builtin Windows picture viewer:

  [image: Picture]

That's clearly not 150 vertical pixels worth of data.